# How to pass vectors(for machine learning) as parameter for functions

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters

I am noobie when it come to python....please he me out...

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
x=input();
y=input();   
theta=input();
def computecost(x,y,theta):
    #some code needing x and y
    print(A)
computecost();
```

I have not coded the cost function but I needs these three parameter for costfunction.

The data coming in through x y and theta are going to be vector ([1,2,3])

THANKYOU

Comment: Can you give some more information? What have you tried? Is there something wrong? I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @Pablo I have change the question...see if it helps....I will also post the Matlab code if it helps...I am actually trying to switch a Matlab code to python

Comment: provide sample data for x,y and theta  and what is expected behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should check out [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).
And note that defining `x`, `y` and `theta` with the same name as the function definition does *not* mean you don't have to pass them (i.e., you have to add them to the call):

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

def computecost(x,y,theta):
    #some code needing x and y
    print(A)

some_x=input();
some_y=input();   
some_theta=input();

computecost(some_x, some_y, some_theta);
```

Comment: Yes...thank you...it worked...I completely forgot about passing arguments during call...so dumb of me

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
x=input();
y=input();   
theta=input();
parameters = np.array([x, y, theta])
def computecost(parameters):
    #some code needing x and y
    print(A)
computecost(parameters);
```

Comment: You still have to pass the parameters in the function call

Comment: Do you want to access x, y and theta inside function, without passing them?